# Tikz + overlay + current page center

Tags: tikz-pgf, overlays

I get a strange behavior with the code below. My goal is to put an image as background and centered. When I run pdflatex, I get a shift in the background image (image 1). When I run pdflatex again (no change to .tex), the position is the right one (no more background color -- ivory, visible). Any idea ?

Thank you so much for any answer.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\title{Background Test Album}
\author{XXX}
\date{XXX}
\geometry{
paperwidth = 210mm,
paperheight = 297mm,
top = 19mm,
bottom = 36.7mm,
left = 19mm,
right = 13.2mm
}
\definecolor{PTAHcolor0}{HTML}{FFFFF0}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{PTAHcolor0}
\noindent
\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \node[inner sep=0] at(current page.center) {\resizebox{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}{\includegraphics{images/back1.png}}};
\noindent\adjustbox{max width=\textwidth, max height=\textheight}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[minimum width=\textwidth, minimum height=\textheight] {};
\node[] at(0.0mm, 0.0mm) {\includegraphics[width=177.8mm, height=241.3mm, keepaspectratio]{photos/woman.jpg}};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is normal behaviour that the image is only positioned right after two runs of LaTeX in such a case. This is because Ti*k*Z only gets to know the correct size of the bounding box in which the image is to be centered *after* the first run (but before the image is initially positioned). So, you need run it twice.

Comment: Thank you. A solution (for 1 pdflatex run) could be that I compute "current page.center" by myself ? From the size of page, margin, etc ?

Comment: BTW, you don't need `\resizebox`: `\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \node[inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height=\paperheight]{images/back1.png}};`.

Comment: Sure, you can place a node at the top left of the page and shift it left and to the top, so that it exactly fits the top left corner of the page. Since you know the size of the margins, this should be doable. But compiling twice is not that much of a problem, I would argue. If you add references, indexing, citations etc. to your document, you also would need to compile multiple times ...

Comment: You're right. Thanks... But this does not solve my main issue. But thanks.